# NSTableView and NSOutlineView drag-and-drop

Tags: cocoa, drag-and-drop, cocoa-bindings, nstableview, nsoutlineview

I have an NSTableView and an NSOutlineView, both with their content provided by bindings, that I'd like to have some drag-and-drop functionality:

- Drag rows from Table A *onto* a row of Outline B, where they will be copied into a data structure which the row in Outline B represents.
- Drag a row from Outline B *onto* another row in Outline B, which will copy the data represented by the first row into the data represented in the second row.

I've read [Apple's drag-and-drop documentation](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/TableView/Tasks/UsingDragAndDrop.html) and gotten just about nowhere. It doesn't really seem to apply to what I need to do. What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need a data source—AFAIK, you can't make this happen with Bindings alone.

The unfinished Adium Xtras Creator, which is under the BSD license, includes [an array controller that you can set as the data source to get drag-and-drop in a Bindings-powered table view](http://hg.adium.im/adium/file/tip/Other/XtrasCreator/AXCArrayControllerWithDragAndDrop.h).

This requirement may not apply to NSOutlineView and NSTreeController. I haven't tried that.

Comment: The link ends up as a 404, and I can't find the original code anywhere.

Comment: Such a perfectly logical and clean way to do this. Thanks for relinking.

Answer (score 7):

The page you linked to is pretty clear about what you need to do. In table A's data source, implement `registerForDraggedTypes:` and `tableView:writeRowsWithIndexes:toPasteboard:` to put some private `TableAPasteboardType` data on the pasteboard.

In outline B's data source, implement the same two methods and put some private `OutlineBPasteboardType` data on the pasteboard.

Finally, implement `tableView:validateDrop:proposedRow:proposedDropOperation:` and `tableView:acceptDrop:row:dropOperation:` to check the pasteboard for either `TableAPasteboardType` or `OutlineBPasteboardType` and make the appropriate changes to your bound model, depending.

It's pretty straightforward once you just plow in and do it.

Answer (score 6):

In MacOS 10.7 some new protocols were added to implement this.

There is a [lack of documentation for tables](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DragandDrop/DragandDrop.html) at the moment but you can find some nice examples:

- [DragNDropOutlineView](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/DragNDropOutlineView/Introduction/Intro.html)
- [SourceView](http://developer.apple.com/library/Mac/#samplecode/SourceView/Introduction/Intro.html)
- [TableViewPlayground](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/TableViewPlayground/Introduction/Intro.html)

For NSTableViwew the Protocol NSTableViewDataSource defines the following methods:

- `(BOOL)tableView:writeRowsWithIndexes:toPasteboard:`
- `tableView:validateDrop:proposedRow:proposedDropOperation:`
- `tableView:acceptDrop:row:dropOperation:`

For NSOutlineView the Protocol NSOutlineViewDataSource defines the following methods:

- `(BOOL)outlineView:writeItems:toPasteboard:`
- `(NSDragOperation)outlineView:validateDrop:proposedItem:proposedChildIndex:`
- `(BOOL)outlineView:acceptDrop:item:childIndex:`

These are the minimum requirements to implement for each view type.
The use cases are quite similar.

1. If the toPasteboard: method returns YES, the drag is started.
2. The validateDrop: method controls which target node is allowed by updating the marker in the view
3. Return YES for the acceptDrop: method if the drop was successful

This lead to two sub-usecases you have to manage. The first one is a drag & drop within the same view or the same operation between two views. Additionally you may distinguish between move, copy or delete operations. A nice example is how the breakpoints work with drag & drop in Xcode.

The tableView has some additional methods to customize drag & drop, but the ones I mentioned are the key methods to get it working.